# mysql select multiple rows with field title value as columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, pivot-table

tables examples

**TABLE**: taxonomy

```
+--+----+
|ID|name|
+--+----+
|1 |demo|
+--+----+
```

**TABLE**: settings

```
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|ID|taxId|title|value|
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|1 |1    |phone|1234 |
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|2 |1    |addr |5678 |
+--+-----+-----+-----+
```

i want **output** like

```
+--+----+-----+----+
|ID|name|phone|addr|
+--+----+-----+----+
|1 |demo|1234 |5678|
+--+----+-----+----+
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
    t.id
    ,t.name
    ,s.value AS s.title 
FROM
    taxonomy t, 
    settings s
WHERE 
    s.taxId = t.id
```

But sure thing it gave me error. Plus I want to loop through all rows of settings to set `s.value` as `s.title` :(

- So is it possible to aggregate all rows from settings table and convert row to use title field as a column header and its value = value field?
- Is this a good way to do this?
- Is there anyway to design my table?

The reason I use such a structure is that / I don't know how many settings I will be needing so I don't want to restrict my self in a single flat table structure.

Comment: This is called a "pivot" -- it's not extremely easy in MySQL; you can look it up.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) useful